# IT Hit WebDAV Server not supporting CARDDAV:addressbook-query

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

Contacts synchronization at least with [davdroid](https://davdroid.bitfire.at/) client doesn’t work well.

This is what I found in IT Hit WebDAV Server log:

```
[11] ----------------- Started: 24.11.2015 15:00:12 -----------------
[11] [REPORT] /addressbooks/webdavuser/Business/
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 184
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: Basic ************************
Host: devel.jablotool.com:50001
User-Agent: DAVdroid/0.9.1.1 (2015/11/24; dav4android) Android/4.2.2
Depth: 1

[11] <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><CARD:addressbook-query xmlns="DAV:" xmlns:CARD="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav"><prop><getetag /></prop><CARD:filter /></CARD:addressbook-query>
[11] HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
X-Env-Version : 4.0.30319.34209 64bit
X-OS-Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
X-IIS-Version : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Worker-Request : System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials : true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : DAV, content-length, Allow
Access-Control-Max-Age : 2147483647
X-Engine : IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v4.0.2416.0 (Evaluation License)
Content-Type : application/xml; charset=utf-8

[11] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:error xmlns:d="DAV:">
  <d:responsedescription>The report is not supported.</d:responsedescription>
</d:error>
[11] ----------------- Finished: 24.11.2015 15:00:12 Took 0ms --------
```

Accoding to the [RFC-6352](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352#page-23)  CARDDAV:addressbook-query REPORT support is required. IT Hit WebDAV Server implementation of CardDAV server returs http status code 405. Is it problem of the client or server implementation of the CardDAV protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I got directly from ItHit:

> Just a quick update regarding addressbook-query support. I was wrong about its 
>   support. Our engine currently supports calendar-query, calendar-multiget and addressbook-multiget, but not addressbook-query. We are working to add its support in the next update.

According to RFC implementation of addressbook-query is required. WebDAVServerEngine version 4.0.2416 is not full implementation of CardDAV protocol.